# Drag item from treeviewer without the viewer getting focus

Tags: drag-and-drop, swt, jface

**Question**

Is there a way to prevent a treeviewer from gaining the focus when starting a drag-and-drop operation? Or do you know another way to prevent it from changing its selection on drag?

**Situation**

- Category 1

  - Note 1.1
- Category 2

  - Note 2.1

I have TreeViewer "categories" that show the categories and 1 TableViewer "notes" that shows the notes within the selected category. The "notes" view content is provided by the selection of the "categories" view through databinding.

**Problem**

When I have Category 1 selected in the "categories" view then I see Note 1.1 in the "notes" view.
The problem is that when I want to drag Category 2 onto Note 1.1 the "categories" view selects Category 2 and I cannot drop the category on Note 1.1 anymore because now the "notes" view shows only Note 2.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you can stop the categories view from getting the focus and firing selection change when you want to start a drag. This just the natural behavior of the controls. There might be some unconventional ways to delay selection firing but they may not work perfectly.

However, to solve your problem I suggest configuring your drag-drop support such that when you start dragging "Category 2" (and consequently changing selection) you first have to hover over "Category 1" (which should re-select "Category 1") and it will allow you to drop "Category 2" on "Note 1.1".

This means that you also add drop support to your categories viewer and in the `DropTargetListener#dragOver(DropTargetEvent)` you set selection to the category the mouse is hovering over. This should start showing your correct note so that you can drop the dragged category over it.